# How to calculate a rolling 52 week high with missing dates and grouping by company ticker (complex data frame)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I have a large dataset with daily stock prices and company codes. I need to compute the 52 week high for each stock at every point in time based on the previous 52 weeks. The problem is that some of the companies do not necessarily have data in between some periods and thus, if I use a fixed window size for a rolling max then the results are not correct.
First I tried this:

```
    df['52wh'] = df["PRC"].groupby(df['id']).shift(1).rolling(253).max()
```

However, this doesn't work since it does not take into account the dates but only the previous 253 entries.
I also tried this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['52wh'] = df.set_index('date').groupby('id').rolling(window=365, freq='D', min_periods=1).max()['PRC']
```

But this gives me this  error:
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

I am thinking maybe a rolling function with get bounds could work but I don't know how to write a good one.

Here is an example of how the data frame looks like

```
          date        id    PRC
0       2010-01-09  10158   11.87
1       2010-01-10  10158   12.30
2       2010-01-11  10158   12.37
3       2010-01-12  10158   12.89
4       2010-02-08  10158   10.13
...        ...       ...     ...
495711  2018-12-12  93188   14.48
495712  2018-12-13  93188   14.48
495713  2018-12-14  93188   14.48
495714  2018-12-17  93188   14.48
495715  2018-12-18  93188   NaN
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: Can you try splitting your data into each stock, then apply the rolling filter? I am guessing that there are some stocks with the same day which is making non-unique indexes when you set the ID to date. Also, please provide some example data in your question

Comment: Yes, indeed the dates are repeating for each stock since I am looking at them over a period of time. I added an example to the question. This is an example from a smaller dataset but the actual datafile contains over 1000 stocks, thus splitting the data into separate stocks wouldn't be efficient right?

Comment: is the "ID" the unique identifier of the stock?

Comment: yes, it's the unique identifier